# Update "Create Tags" documentation for sites that permit Unicode tags

Tags: bug, tag-creation, unicode, privileges-page

[/help/privileges/create-tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) reads as follows on all sites:

> Simply enter a new tag with your question and it will be created. When creating your new tag, bear in mind that tags ...
>
> - must be shorter than 25 characters
> - must use the character set `a-z` `0-9` `+` `#` `-` `.`

However, this is not accurate for sites that permit Unicode tags (including, at minimum, Spanish, Russian, ru.SO, Japanese, ja.SO, and Chinese) - lots of characters outside the ASCII range can also be used.

Comment: I even believe all characters, except the | (pipe) symbol, are allowed on all sites, based on [this](http://blog.marcgravell.com/2014/04/technical-debt-case-study-tags.html)